# Файл .exe в файл .py

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл с расширением ***.exe*** , надо его декомпилировать в  ***.py*** ( версия **python** 3.9.5 ). Как это сделать?

Всё что я находил работали только до версии **python** 3.8.0

Answer (score 3):

EXE на питоне это обычный архив с PYC скомпилированными файлами. В 3.8 и 3.9 сделанна новая машина для байткода. Суда по записям ,например, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66989736/2101808 автор декомпилятора ещё не доделал поддержку 3.9 - надо подождать. Следите за новостями
тут https://github.com/rocky/python-decompile3/issues/45 и тут https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/issues/331