# Python не видет pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Установил pyinstaller через pip, вроде бы все норм, но когда пишу pyinstaller пишет:

```
$ pyinstaller
"pyinstaller" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Вот лог установки pyinstaller:

```
$ pip install pyinstaller
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\users\daniil\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\daniil\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\daniil\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in c:\users\daniil\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\daniil\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2021.5.24)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8" in c:\users\daniil\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (47.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\daniil\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1; sys_platform == "win32"->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4; python_version < "3.8" in c:\users\daniil\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->pyinstaller) (3.10.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\daniil\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->pyinstaller) (3.4.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.1.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\daniil\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Уточните, какой версии питон. Ибо согласно оффициальной документации, начаная с версии питона 3.8+, поддержка pyinstaller заканчивается.
Ставить pyinstaller желательно на версию питона 3.7.4
Вот ссылка: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374/
Качать эту версию: Windows x86 executable installer Windows     33cc602942a54446a3d6451476394789    25663848    SIG

Comment: А чем пользоваться взамен pyinstaller?

Comment: @helldrg, Ну больше библиотек я не знаю. После версии питона 3.8+, pyinstaller не поддерживается, остаётся кодить в C или C++, если уж переводить в .exe-шник.

Comment: на официальном сайте pyinstaller написано, что поддерживает питон вплоть до 3.9 и никакой информации про окончании поддержки нету

Comment: Хм, не знаю, почему мои попытки установить pyinstaller на версии 3.8 и позже, окончились теме же проблемами, что и описано в этом вопросе.

Comment: ... у меня питон версия 3.7 и у меня просто нету команды pyinstaller в path, но он установлен в

Comment: c:\users\daniil\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages

Comment: там есть pyinstaller и я не знаю как его запускать т.к он у меня в path не добавился почему-то

Comment: @Daniilus, Объяснять по опыту, будет много писанины, но дам два совета:

1. Переустановите питон, и нажмите на галочку "Add Python to Path", она в самом начале установки, в самом низу окошка с установкой.

2. Посмотри видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgCJwDjm_Cw, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aL-4bSPWU04

Comment: @helldrg, Это конечно чу-чуть не по теме, но в комментариях всё же относительно самого pyinstaller-а тема касается: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1302523/%d0%a4%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-exe-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-py

Comment: БОже, у меня питон есть в path, a pyinstaller нету

Comment: ты сообщение не правильно написал

Comment: точнее прочитал

Comment: и посмотрите тему. Там видно что pyinstaller установлен и у меня версия питона 3.7

Comment: @Daniilus, pyinstaller в path тоже надо добавить. Нужно абсолютный путь до него прописать. Я когда в первый раз устанавливал, аналогичная проблема была.

Comment: Я чуть выше добавил видео от Хауди Хо, там наглядно объяснили как его добавлять.

Comment: чел... там просто установка pyinstaller

Comment: а все, прости я там увидел про pyinstaller

Comment: Кстати, почитай логи, попробуй обновить pip: You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\daniil\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Команда для его обновления: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Бро, прими ответ. Кнопочка Галочки рядом с моим ответом. Плиз.